# Regex Detect urls and make the link <a>

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex and I try to find all the url to create the link () but I have the following problems:

- Some url with "\foo\bar" don't get them
- the url takes it as part of the web.

www.foo.com  -> https://mywebsite.com/section/www.foo.com

it is possible that if it is a link that does not have https it will be put automatically (avoiding the ftp or \ hostname or \ ip) ???

Thanks !

Live Regex: 
https://regex101.com/r/w3o9w1/1

Regex:

```
/(?:(?:https?|ftp|):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))?/gm
```

Text Demo:

```
text www.example.com  text text text http://example.com 

\\hadgs01\test2
http://192.168.1.1:3000/
192.168.1.1:3000
\\192.168.10.10\test\test.txt

http://example.com
http://example.gl
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/bar
https://example.com/icons?d=bar&q=bar
http://abc.dec.ed.example.com
http://example.gl/1 http://example.gl/2
foo (http://example.gl/1) http://example.gl/(2)
http://example.com/. http://example.com/! http://example.com/,
example.gl/1
http://example.com/review/abc-def-ghi/?ct=t(test_test_bar)


www.example.com.au
http://www.example.com.au
http://www.example.com.au/ersdfs
http://www.example.com.au/bar?dfd=test@s=1
http://www.example.com:81/bar.html
```

Code:

```
 var regex_links = /(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))?/gm;

$(".text_to_replace").html($(".text_to_replace").html().replace(regex_links, " <a href=\"$&\" target='_blank'>$&</a> "));
```

Comment: @Mandy8055 nope "\\hadgs01\test2" or "\\192.168.10.10\test\test.tx" have not included

Comment: @Mandy8055 "ftp://192.168.178.11/asd" -> "ftp://https://192.168.178.11/asd"  have not ignored ftp protocol :/ , i can make this if($1 != 'ftp')  ??

Comment: @Mandy8055 yes, in case I don't have a protocol, I will give it https, and in case I have "\\ example \" I don't do anything

Comment: i think ist better ignore when have spaces.

Comment: @Mandy8055 I just adapted it to jquery and if it works for me, the only thing missing is the "\\192.168.10.10\test\ test.txt" and "\\hadgs01\test2" Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is pretty close to your expectations;  but in order to match the strings for your requirement(**matching "\\hadgs01\test2" or "\\192.168.10.10\test\test.txt"**) you can use the below regex:

```
(?:(https?|ftp)?:?\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))?
```

**Changes made in your regex:**

> **`(?:https?|ftp|):`** **changed to** **`(https?|ftp|)?:?`** - I made the following modifications to your regex in order to capture the group for your second requirement as well as to match the desired strings of sorts `\\hadgs01\test2` and `\\192.168.10.10\test\test.txt`.

**IMPLEMENTATION IN JAVASCRIPT:**

```js
const myRegexp = /(?:(https?|ftp)?:?\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))?/gm;
const myString = `
text www.example.com  text text text http://example.com 
//hadgs01/test2
http://192.168.1.1:3000/
192.168.1.1:3000
\\\\192.168.10.10\\test\\test.txt

http://example.com
http://examp.ele
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/bar
https://example.com/icons?d=bar&q=bar
http://abc.dec.ed.example.com
http://examp.le/1 http://examp.ele/2
foo (http://examp.ele/1) http://examp.ele/(2)
http://example.com/. http://example.com/! http://example.com/,
examp.le/1
http://example.com/review/abc-def-ghi/?ct=t(test_test_bar)
www.example.com.au
http://www.example.com.au
http://www.example.com.au/ersdfs
http://www.example.com.au/bar?dfd=test@s=1
http://www.example.com:81/bar.html
\\ example \\\\
`;

// PLEASE NOTE I REPLACED FOO and goo.gle from the string to example and examp.ele because of the norms
let match;
// Taken the below variable to store the result
let resultString = "";
match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
while (match != null) {
// If group 1 of match is null that means it does'nt contain anything among https, http or ftp but it match rest of the requirement.
  if(match[1] == null)
  // If in case the link already contains slashes like //hadgs01/test2
    if(match[0].includes('//'))
      resultString = resultString.concat("https:" + match[0] + "\n");
    else
      resultString = resultString.concat("https://" + match[0] + "\n");
  else
    resultString = resultString.concat(match[0] + "\n");
  
  match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
console.log(resultString);
```

Comment: /(?:(https?|ftp)?:\/\/|\\\\|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))?/gm

Comment: I have improved the regex a little to skip when a string ends in a dot, but I have a problem with dates that have dot inside, could you help me with that?. The IPs are 0-255 in 4 blocks (never 4 digits) . Thank you !  https://regex101.com/r/Y7Ek2b/2 (

Comment: In that case; you need to embed IP validation in your regex since Date can be of max 4 digits(year) after dot; but then the regex will be very cumbersome.